# JQuery, Find and replace text if found in a var array

Tags: jquery, html, arrays

We've got a feed into our site which doesn't separate the Product Brand and Product Name, from the Product Title:

```
<div class="productTitle">Brand 1 Product Name</div>
```

and we want to seperate the Brand so we can wrap it in it's own div and style it different:

```
<div class="productTitle"><div class="brandName">Brand 1</div> Product Name</div>
```

There is a list of filters (you can filter brands by) available that contains all the brand names.

So what I've been trying to do is take all the text from each item in the list:

```
<ul class="filters">
    <li>Brand 1</li>
    <li>Brand 2</li>
    <li>Brand 3</li>
    <li>Brand 4</li>
</ul>
```

store them as an array and then if any of the items in the array are found in the Product Title text, wrap that part in it's own div to style up.

I've got this far to store the each item in the list in an array but can't get it to correctly look at the entire array and if it finds any matching text in each product title wrap that matching text:

```
var brandText =[];
$('.filters li').each(function(index, obj) {
  brandText.push($(this).text());
});




$('.productTitle').html(function (index, text) {
  this.innerHTML = text.replace(brandText, "<div class='brandName'>" + brandText + "</div>");
});

$(window).ajaxComplete(function(){
  $('.productTitle').html(function (index, text) {
    this.innerHTML = text.replace(brandText, "<div class='brandName'>" + brandText + "</div>");
  });
});
```

When I console.log the var **brandText** it returns all 122 brands in the console but it's not finding the text in each of the product titles (usually 60 products per page) and wrap that text.

Can anyone help please?

Thanks

Comment: brandText is an array, I don't think you can pass an array into .replace, you would need to loop the array and replace each one separately (not sure if there would be a more efficient way)

Answer (score 0):

Since brandText is an array of brands, you will have to **loop** through each and every brand.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to iterate through the `brandText` array and replace all occurrences if they are present. Something like this will suffice:

```
$('.productTitle').html(function(index, text) {
    brandText.forEach(function(brand) {
        text = text.replace(brand, "<div class='brandName'>" + brand + "</div>");
    });
    return text;
});
```

See proof-of-concept below:

```js
$(function() {
  var brandText = [];
  $('.filters li').each(function(index, obj) {
    brandText.push($(this).text());
  });

  $('.productTitle').html(function(index, text) {
    brandText.forEach(function(brand) {
      text = text.replace(brand, "<div class='brandName'>" + brand + "</div>");
    });
    return text;
  });
});
```

```css
.brandName {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="filters">
  <li>Brand 1</li>
  <li>Brand 2</li>
  <li>Brand 3</li>
  <li>Brand 4</li>
</ul>

<div class="productTitle">Brand 1 Product Name</div>
<div class="productTitle">Brand 2 Product Name</div>
<div class="productTitle">Brand 3 Product Name</div>
<div class="productTitle">Brand 4 Product Name</div>
```

---

Additional optimisation:

- You can use `.map()` to create the initial array, i.e:

  ```
  var brandText = $('.filters li').map(function() {
      return $(this).text();
  });
  ```
- Abstract the entire replacement logic in a method, so that you simply have to invoke the method on AJAX complete (instead of having to duplicate your code)

  ```
  var replaceBrandText = function() {
    $('.productTitle').html(function(index, text) {
      brandText.forEach(function(brand) {
        text = text.replace(brand, "<div class='brandName'>" + brand + "</div>");
      });
      return text;
    });
  };

  // Replace on DOM ready (at runtime)
  replaceBrandText();

  // Replace on AJAX complete
  $(window).ajaxComplete(function(){
    replaceBrandText();
  });
  ```